# ImageMagick C++ API get channels of image

Tags: c++, api, imagemagick

I want to retrieve information about how channels in an image are used.
Used library ImageMagick version 6.9.1, Qt5, C++.

```
QString ImageMagick::test(){
    qDebug()<<"magickimage test";
    Magick::Image magickimage;
    try {
        magickimage.read(qUtf8Printable("poster383x357.jpg"));
    }
    catch (Magick::Warning &error_ ) {
        qDebug()<<QString("Warning %1").arg(error_.what());
        return "";
    }
    catch (Magick::Error &error_ ) {
        qDebug()<<QString("Error %1").arg(error_.what());
        return "";
    }
    if (magickimage.isValid()){
        qDebug()<<"magickimage w x h:"<<magickimage.columns()<<magickimage.rows();
        qDebug()<<"magickimage depth"<<magickimage.depth();
        int channels = (int)MagickCore::GetImageChannels(magickimage.image());
        qDebug()<<"magickimage channels:"<<channels;
    }
    return "";
}
```

But the return is:

```
magickimage test
magickimage w x h: 383 357
magickimage depth 8
channels: 0
```

I know that image (`poster383x357.jpg`) have 24 bits per pixel  24/8=3 channels.
Answer must be `channels: 3`.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the ellipsis, and demonstrate what you're expecting?  The given results _would_ be expected from the example code provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Updated answer...

Remember the channel count is subjective to the colorspace. The `MagickCore::ImageInfo` structure will contain a `channel` property; which, is an enumerator of `ChannelType`. Using bitwise comparison, and respecting colorspace, the total channels in an image can be calculated as...

```cpp
Magick::Image img("rose:");
MagickCore::ImageInfo * info = img.imageInfo();
int channel_count = 0;

// Have Red, or Cyan (CMYK), or Gray
if ((info->channel & Magick::RedChannel) != 0) channel_count++;

// Have Green, or Magenta (CMYK)
if ((info->channel & Magick::GreenChannel) != 0) channel_count++;

// Have Blue, or Yellow (CMYK)
if ((info->channel & Magick::BlueChannel) != 0) channel_count++;

// Check for Alpha channel (if enabled)
if (((info->channel & Magick::OpacityChannel) != 0)
   && (img.matte() != Magick::MagickFalse)) channel_count++;

// Have Black channel in CMYK image
if (((info->channel & Magick::IndexChannel) != 0)
   && (img.colorSpace() == Magick::CMYKColorspace)) channel_count++;

std::cout << "Total channels : " << channel_count << std::endl;
//=> Total channels : 3
```

### Original answer...

If you are attempting to evaluate how the channels are laid out, then you should evaluate the colorspace of the image with `Magick::Image.colorSpace`, or even `Magick::Image.magick` if you're working with format types. In IM-6, this is usually 4 (`RGBA`), or 5 (`CMYKA`) channels, and how the data occupies the channels are assumed by the colorspace.

You can use `Magick::quantizeInfo` to evaluate how the data is structured in memory(?).

```cpp
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const MagickCore::QuantizeInfo& info)
{
  os << "number of colors : " << info.number_colors << std::endl;
  os << "tree depth       : " << info.tree_depth << std::endl;
  os << "dither           : " << info.dither << std::endl;
  return os;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
  Magick::InitializeMagick(argv[0]);
  Magick::Image img("rose:");
  MagickCore::QuantizeInfo * qInfo = img.quantizeInfo();
  std::cout << "Quantize Info\n" << *qInfo << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Which would output something like...

```
Quantize Info
number of colors : 256
tree depth       : 0
dither           : 1
```

**If you're attempting to determine statistics...** than `Magick::Image.statistics` would be ideal. Example...

```cpp
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Magick::Image::ImageChannelStatistics& channel)
{
  os << "maximum  : " << channel.maximum << std::endl;
  os << "minimum  : " << channel.minimum << std::endl;
  os << "mean     : " << channel.mean << std::endl;
  os << "std dev  : " << channel.standard_deviation << std::endl;
  os << "skewness : " << channel.skewness << std::endl;
  os << "kurtosis : " << channel.kurtosis << std::endl;
  return os;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
  Magick::InitializeMagick(argv[0]);
  Magick::Image img("rose:");
  Magick::Image::ImageStatistics stats;
  img.statistics(&stats);
  std::cout << "Red\n---\n" << stats.red << std::endl;
  // ...
  return 0;
}
```

Which would give...

```
Red
---
maximum  : 65535
minimum  : 8995
mean     : 37448
std dev  : 17808.9
skewness : 0.14637
kurtosis : -1.385
```

### In ImageMagick 7

The next major release of ImageMagick supports any amount of pixel channels from 1-32+. See [Porting -> Pixel Channel](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/porting.php#channels) guide. This version will introduce a method `GetPixelChannels` which might be the behavior you're expecting.

```cpp
 // Un-tested and subject to change
 int channels = MagickCore::GetPixelChannels(magickimage.image());
```

### But I digress

> What is wrong?

The `GetImageChannels` returns 0 because you haven't set any channels.

```cpp
size_t channels = MagickCore::GetImageChannels(img.image());
std::cout << channels << std::endl; //=> 0
MagickCore::SetImageChannels(img.image(), 1);
channels = MagickCore::GetImageChannels(img.image());
std::cout << channels << std::endl; //=> 1
```

Comment: `qDebug()<<"magickimage colorSpace:"<<magickimage.colorSpace();`

magickimage colorSpace: 13

Comment: That would be an enumerator value of the `sRGB` colorspace. Updated answer with example

Comment: IM7 has magickImage->channels(). I will try and see if I can also add this to IM6.

Comment: @dlemstra , Would that be easy w/o `number_channels` on `struct _Image`? But I guess a quick calculation would still be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: acceptable solution:
if ((info->channel & Magick::RedChannel) != 0) channel_count++;...
thanks